# Firebase: Storage upload file size limit?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

What is the [Firebase Storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/) upload file size limit? I can't find that information on the website.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/how-tos/upload

> Any MIME type of data is permitted, up to a maximum of 5 TB per file.

The Firebase Storage libraries don't impose any additional size restrictions. But given that you're targeting mobile devices, I expect that there's a more realistic limit you will hit before that.